# Insert value in Incremental List not working

Tags: python, list, loops, insert

**Context:**

This code is really simple, I´m just new to python. I have an incremental list of numbers, all I need to do is check if there is any missing value, and if I do, insert -1 in that position, example:

If I have a list with values [1,2,4,5], I want it to become [1,2,-1,4,5].

If I have a list with values [1,4,5], I want it to become [1,-1,-1,4,5].

Simple, yet I can´t do it properly on python.

**My code:**

**id:** The list I want to modify.

**i, j, and z:** Counters.

**MyRange**: I can´t show the real name of the variable (I don´t own the code), but the range is correct.

```
z=0
for i in MyRange:
       value = id[i]
       value2 = id[i+1]
       j=z
       //This while is here because I try not to compare a value with -1
       //(I think this is the problem)
       while value == -1:
            j=j-1
            value = id[j]
       if(int(value)+1 == int(value2)):
            if(value2 != -1):
                  id.insert(i,-1)
       z=z+1
```

This code identifies any missing value, but then fills the rest of the list (From the missing value to the last value with -1).

Any help would be apprecciated. Thank you and sorry for any english mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One somewhat easy way to do this is to make a set of the numbers.  Then you can count from the lowest to the biggest and look for the number in the set.  If it's there, you're all good.  If it's not there, then yield a `-1`.

```
def fill_range(initial_range, fill_vallue):
    smallest = initial_range[0]
    biggest = initial_range[-1]
    items = set(initial_range)
    for i in range(smallest, biggest+1):  # use xrange on python2.x
        if i in items:
            yield i
        else:
            yield fill_value
```

You might use this generator function like this:

```
print(list(fill_range([1,2,4,5], -1)))
```

---

If you haven't seen a generator function before, they're worth learning about but the answer above might be slightly confusing.  Here's a version which accumulates a list and then returns it at the end:

```
def fill_range(initial_range, fill_vallue):
    result = []
    smallest = initial_range[0]
    biggest = initial_range[-1]
    items = set(initial_range)
    for i in range(smallest, biggest+1):
        if i in items:
            result.append(i)
        else:
            result.append(fill_value)
    return result
```

<sup>You might also notice that the `if` `else` suite could be replaced here pretty easily by a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)...</sup>

Comment: I'm going to assume you made a typo in the first code snippet: `biggest = initial_range[-1]`

Comment: @Kendas -- Yep.  Definitely a typo which got copy/pasted into the second code snippet..  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, but I already have my list created, i´m not creating it, i just edit it. Also, my range is from 0 to lastIndex of the list, I have no idea what values the List can have, might be from 0 to 1000 or from 56783 to 696280. (Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I just got this code today and never programmed python in my life)

Comment: @Mayuso -- For operations like this, it's generally _more_ efficient to generate a new list than it is to edit the original list.  The reason for this is simple -- each insert into a list is an O(N) operation whereas the algorithm I've laid out here is O(N) for the whole thing (at the expense of a bit more memory).

Comment: @mgilson I just left the office when I posted the question, so I can´t implement this into my code, but I get the idea, I know how to do it, that´s enough, will do it tomorrow without any problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one additional variable to keep track of missing elements of the sequence.

```
def insert_minus_ones(lst):
    new_lst = []
    last = lst[0] - 1
    for e in lst:
        while (last + 1) != e:
            new_lst.append(-1)
            last += 1
        new_lst.append(e)
        last += 1
    return new_lst
```

The code above works for any sequences of numbers:

```
>>> insert_minus_ones([1,2,4,6,10])
[1, 2, -1, 4, -1, 6, -1, -1, -1, 10]

>>> insert_minus_ones([-5,-4,-3,2])
[-5, -4, -3, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2]
```